# Azure startup.cmd add new user script

Tags: azure, startupscript, startup.cmd

I have a simple startup.cmd script which runs some net commands to create a new user and add the user to the administrator group.

I got the script from [this blog](http://devlicio.us/blogs/vinull/archive/2011/10/23/moving-to-azure-worker-roles-for-nothing-and-tasks-for-free.aspx).  I have run the net commands in a elevated CMD session and they work correctly.  but running this on my developer machine just sees the role hanging.

Is there some trick i'm missing?

startup.cmd file contents:
net user dataAdmin thepassword /add
net localgroup Administrators dataAdmin /add

the relevant snippet from the servicedefinition file:

the startup.cmd is set to build action = Content and Copy Always for the copy to output directory

I haven't tried this in azure production yet.  I will attempt to push it into staging later today.

**UPDATE**
At BStateham's suggestion I checked the event logs on my machine:
Under 'Windows Azure' there is a error logged:

User program "..\SLC.DataRole\approot\bin\startup.cmd"  exited with non-zero exit code 1

Any idea what that is supposed to mean?

Comment: Have you looked in the compute emulator for your instance? Any information in the log there?

Comment: in the event logs - User program "F:\Projects\SLC\Database\SLC.AzureProject\csx\Debug\roles\SLC.DataRole\approot\bin\startup.cmd"  exited with non-zero exit code 1

Comment: It's possible that it is failing on your dev box because the account already exists.  You might create a Pre-Build or Post-Build script in your project that deletes the user account prior to running the project on the local dev box.

Comment: I check to make sure of this.  The new account has not being made so far via this script (only manually via cmd - which I then removed)

Comment: I'm getting similar behavior.  However, if I modify the startup task to not include the "net *" commands, it runs.  Feels like a permissions issue to me. Is your developer machine domain joined?

Comment: getting somewhere.  there was a stupid text encoding issue.  saved as ansi encoding and working now.  also need to pick a shorter password to avoid a confirmation prompt

Comment: I got mine working as well.  Problem was I was using your script with "thepassword" as dataAdmin's password.  My machine policy was preventing that.  It works now for me.  Let me know if you continue to have problems.

Comment: My azure machine has changed the default password policy to require complexity - broke my site without warning!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments it looks like you discovered this but a critical requirement is that the startup cmd file has the correct encoding, and

> "Be sure to create it with notepad or another ASCII text editor… batch
>   files created in Visual Studio seem to have a byte order mark at the
>   top that makes them fail when executed."

Also [this](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-startup-tasks-tips-tricks-and-gotchas) and this [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129545.aspx) are good references for some other common issues with startup commands.